# Trigger over 3 tables on mysql

Tags: mysql, mariadb

i want to make a trigger insert into another table after delete. i have 3 tables ( A, B , C ). if I delete from Table A, records on table B that related  to table A will move into table C.

I already tried this,

`create trigger deleteA after delete on A`
    `-> for each row`
    `-> begin`
    `-> insert into C (PKid_A,id_B)` -->here i want take the B values for inserting to C
    `-> values`
    `-> (old.PKid_A, old.id_B);`
    `-> end//`

but, it wasn't working

Answer (score 0):

I think you miss out the join between A and B so that it will take those value that relate to A and will insert into table C

For example

```
CREATE TRIGGER triggername AFTER DELETE on A
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
INSERT INTO C
        ([c.columnname], [c.columnname])
    SELECT
        [B.columnname],[B.columnname] from B inner join on 
       A on B.id = old.id;
END
```

Comment: where should I put value syntax? is it after select ?

Comment: Which value syntax you are saying. Please explain in example

Comment: values (old.PKid_A, old.id_B) <- this syntax. this syntax is necessary or not?

Comment: Actually we have put select query under insert command so you can put those column which you want then specify into select column so it will automatically pick those column. No need to write values syntax.